# Leaflet: Filter Markers

Tags: leaflet

For example I have layerGroup:

```
marker1: {color: red, age: 15, type: 'fruit'}
marker2: {color: red, age: 10, type: 'animal'}
marker3: {color: green, age: 10, type: 'fruit'}
marker4: {color: green, age: 11, type: 'animal'}
```

And I want to show markers with color: red and also show markers with age 10

Answer (score 1):

Add all markers in a array and loop it through. Then add it to a layergroup/featuregroup.

```
var fg = L.featureGroup().addTo(mymap);

var markers = [marker1,marker2,marker3,marker4];

mymap.on('click moveend', function(e){
  fg.clearLayers();
  markers.forEach(function(marker){
    var options = marker.options
    if(options){
        if(options.color && options.color == "red"){
        fg.addLayer(marker);
      }else if(options.age && options.age == 10){
        fg.addLayer(marker);
      }
    } 
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/vxz6pon7/